# Facebook Ads API - get ad account balance in real time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api, facebook-insights

I trying to get an Ad Account's balance (Bill amount due) using this API endpoint:
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{ad_account_id}?fields=balance

Unfortunately this API method return old data. **4 hours and older**... How to get a fresh data like we can get manually at facebook.com/ads/manager/account_settings/account_billing
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os2iq.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You maybe can estimate that from spend report for ad account from previous bill... but that can be even less accurate...

```
act_{ad_account_id}/insights?fields=spend&time_range={'since':'2018-11-02','until':'2018-12-02'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read in AdAccount attribute. For me, has been updated.

```
$accounts = $user->getAdAccounts(
        array(
            'balance',
            'amount_spent'
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having this doubt? It was quite difficult to find the answer to this solution.

After many hours I understood how the remaining account balance is calculated. you can make a request.

Send a request to https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/act_xxxxxxx?fields=amount_spent,balance,spend_cap
as an example I will show the return of my request

{
"amount_spent": "5120944",
"balance": "986",
"spend_cap": "5304148",
"id": "act_xxxxxx"
}

Now I will show how the calculation is done. Remembering that my currency is BRL

The amount_spent field represents the total amount of money that has been spent on advertising for the account, and the spend_cap field represents the maximum amount of money that can be spent on advertising for the account.

To calculate the current balance, you can subtract the amount_spent value from the spend_cap value. This will give you the remaining amount of money that can be spent on advertising.

For example, if the amount_spent value is "5120924" and the spend_cap value is "5304148", then the current balance is 5304148 - 5120924 = 183224 units of the account currency.

Units of The currency? Yes, I realized that in my case it brings the number in units (cents) so I divided it by 100 and got R$ 1.832,24.

But I looked in the ads manager and the balance there is R$ 1,842.10

Now let's understand the balance field: Bill amount due for this Ad Account.
So, 986/100 = R$ 9,86 + R$ 1.832,24 = R$ 1.842,10. Yeeeeaahhhhhhhhh

Here is an example image of the request and print of the ad account https://www.linkpicture.com/q/requet_example.png